# How to move SharePoint authentication from AD to LDAP without breaking user profiles?

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, ldap

We have a bunch of users in a local Active Directory OU that access the SharePoint portal.  We've just added LDAP authentication and pointed it at the organisation's global LDAP server, so out AD accounts are now redundant.
Is there a way to re-map the authentication for a SharePoint (MOSS 2007) user/profile.

That is, can we manually change a lot of users so that they log in with their LDAP credentials and get the same SharePoint MySite, groups, etc. as when they were authenticating via AD?

Comment: ouch! Too bad they didn't choose to use AD for LDAP instead.  Great question!

Comment: Can you just proxy AD back to the LDAP server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you are going to need the [stsadm migrateuser command.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262141.aspx)

I think for the mysites, you are also going to need to update the owner of the site using the [stsadm siteowner command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262637.aspx).

The mysites could get weird depending on how you have them setup. If the sites are just /personal/username, (and the username is the same from AD to LDAP) then you should be OK. If they are /personal/domain_username (or the username changes from AD to LDAP) then you may also need to actually change the url of each users mysite. This would get messy because there is no built in command to do it - the only option would be to backup each site and restore to a new site collection with the new username.

PS - I've never done this, I'm just theorizing based on available commands in SharePoint...